# No Module named Contact Error-Chapter 7 Exercise in Django Book

Tags: python, django, forms

I've received the following error when trying to set up a contact subdirectory inside the mysite directory.

Here is how I structured the `urls.py` script:

```
from mysite.contact import views as contact_views

(r'^contact/$', contact_views.contact),
```

Do I need to change anything in the `settings.py` `TEMPLATE_DIRS`, so, I can call the `contact_form.html` template correctly?

Comment: What's the structure for your modules?

This is most likely a path issue.

Comment: Have you created a `__init__.py` file (even empty) in that directory? Without it, python will not recognize your module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, template_dirs needs to contain the path to the templates folder.